# Grails / GORM criteria query with hasmany String

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, createcriteria

I have a domain object (Cat) like this:

```
class Cat {
   String name

   static hasMany = [
      nicknames: String
   ]
}
```

(A cat has a name, and also has many nicknames (which are Strings))

And I am trying to query all the cats with certain nicknames.

I've tried this:

```
PagedResultList getCatsByNickname(String nickname, Map params) {
   PagedResultList results = Cat.createCriteria().list(params) {
      'ilike'('nicknames','%'+nickname+'%')
   }
   return results
}
```

But it never returns any results. (If I change the query to just use the simple name attribute, it works finding all cats with that name, but I want to query against the nicknames.)

I also tried this:

```
PagedResultList getCatsByNickname(String nickname, Map params) {
   PagedResultList results = Cat.createCriteria().list(params) {
      'nicknames' {
         'ilike'('nicknames','%'+nickname+'%')
       }
   }
   return results
}
```

But I get the error: org.hibernate.MappingException: collection was not an association: example.Cat.nicknames

So the question is, how do I query against a hasMany of type String?

Comment: Some people asking the same question: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Criteria-query-on-properties-of-type-List-lt-String-gt-td1325707.html
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GORM-how-to-set-criteria-for-object-with-list-or-set-of-strings-td1388277.html

Comment: This bug appears to be the cause of the error you are getting: [GRAILS-5887](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5887)

Answer (score 15):

After a lot of trying and researching, I found this will work with Grails 2.4.0, I don't know about older versions.

```
Cat.withCriteria {
    createAlias('nicknames', 'n') 
    ilike 'n.elements', '%kitty%'
}
```

The trick is to use 'n.**elements**'

Comment: I still get "org.hibernate.MappingException: collection was not an association" when using this method in 2.4.0

Comment: This worked for me and I think this is not documented anywhere in the Grails doc. Thanks.

Comment: This works for me and I cannot find any document about this

Answer (score 8):

You can use HQL for querying in such a scenario. For example,

```
Cat.findAll("from Cat c where :nicknames in elements(c.nicknames)", [nicknames:'kitty'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!    
Okay, this gets me started, but how do I say I want nicknames **like** kitty?

Comment: I think that findAll uses PostgreSQL syntax, so try %kitty%

Comment: %kitty% doesn't work. i tried this on mysql and hibernate generates a sql that looks "select * 
    from
        cat c
    where
        'kitty' in (
            select
                nicknames_string
            from
                cat_nicknames n
            where
                c.id=n.cat_id
        )"     ....unfortunately it seems like you would need to use an OR clause (nickname like %kitty%' OR nickname like '%timmy%' OR ...)

Comment: Right... I was thinking of Like or Ilike.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use HQL (tested with Grails 2.5.0):

```
Cat.findAll("from Cat c inner join c.nicknames as n where upper(n) like '%'||?||'%'", [nickname.toUpperCase()])
```