# Grails: find by one-to-many association with String

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a following domain class:

```
class User {
   static hasMany = [roles:String]
}
```

I would like to find every user which has role `ROLE_ADMIN`. Is there any possibility to do that with dynamic finders? `user.findAllByRoles('ROLE_ADMIN')` seems to give me an error.

UPDATE: it is quite easy to query association where Class `A` has a list of class `B` instances and both `A` and `B` are domain classes. But here class `A` is a domain class and class `B` is a simple Java string.

The code for querying association containing list of another domain objects would look like this:

```
`User.findAll { roles { role_name=='ROLE_ADMIN' } }`
```

What i am looking for is a way to specify the value of a String, for example:

```
`User.findAll { roles {THIS_VALUE=='ROLE_ADMIN' }}`
```

UPDATE 2: as far as i have found it is not possible to use criteria with collections of primitive types. It is possible to use HQL though:

```
User.findAll("from User a where :roles in elements(roles)",[roles:'ROLE_ADMIN'])
```

However it is not as usefull as a `findAll` or `where` query. I cannot chain `findAll` methods so defining other methods that for example: get `ROLE_ADMIN` users with username like 'xxx' requires rewriting whole `HQL` query. Maybe it is possible to express above `HQL` condition in form of a `where` expression?

Comment: What error do you get? Simply saying you get one is less than useful.

Comment: It just does not work, gives error about incorrect hibernate query (that param #1 is not set), and i see a `where id=?` in the query therefore i think the `findAllByRoles` method did not have any effect. I think there must be another way of querying associations which contain simple types like `String`

Comment: Check the solution using GORM criteria here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24211973/3738761

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can do something like:

if you have already a user list (userList)

```
def list = userList.findAll { user -> user.roles =~ 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I think this criteria code does not work... what does `tags` mean here?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem [How to find records by value in their association property via DetachedCriteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026161/how-to-find-records-by-value-in-their-association-property-via-detachedcriteria)

I made some investigation and, as I found, it's impossible.
The GORM DSL itself doesn't have any method to check that value contains in association.
It conains oly that criterias that are in SQL: `AND`, `OR`, `IN`.

But! You can join association as table in criteria [Querying by Association Redux](http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/06/querying-by-association-redux.html)